# Retornar json de query inner join ASP.NET WEB app C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Boa tarde pessoal. Estou tentando retornar o resultado de uma query com INNER JOIN em uma API REST em C# mas não estou conseguindo,não posso usar frameworks, tem que ser na base do código, já procurei bastante mas só acho com frameworks, segue me u código;
TO:

```
  public class Marca
        {
            public int MarcaId { get; set; }
            public string Nome { get; set; }
            public Patrimonio patrimonio;
        }
```

Repositório:

```
public List<Marca> GetComposto(int marcaId)
    {
        List<Marca> marcas = new List<Marca>();
        List<Patrimonio> patrimonios = new List<Patrimonio>();
        SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand();
        connection.Open();
        query.Connection = connection;
        query.CommandText = @"SELECT Patrimonio.Nome, Patrimonio.MarcaId, NumeroTombo, Descricao FROM Marca INNER JOIN Patrimonio ON  Marca.MarcaId = Patrimonio.MarcaId  WHERE Marca.MarcaId = @marcaId;";

        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@marcaId", marcaId);

        SqlDataReader leitura = query.ExecuteReader();

        while (leitura.Read())
        {
            Marca marca = new Marca();
            Patrimonio patrimonio = new Patrimonio();
            marca.patrimonio.Nome = (string)leitura["Nome"];
            marca.patrimonio.MarcaId =  (int)leitura["MarcaId"];
            marca.patrimonio.NumeroTombo = (int)leitura["NumeroTombo"];
            marca.patrimonio.Descricao = (string)leitura["Descricao"];

            marcas.Add(marca);

        }
        return marcas;
    }
```

Controller:

```
[Route("api/marca/patrimonio")] 
    public List<Marca> GetComposto(int marcaId)
    {
        try
        {
            using (RepositorioMarca conexao = new RepositorioMarca())
            {
                marcas = conexao.GetComposto(marcaId);
                return marcas;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Esta dando o erro: "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto" na Classe de repositório, em todas as linhas que tento construir o patrimonio(marca.patrimonio.Nome, marca.patrimonio.MarcaId...

Comment: Consegui entender o problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está em tentar acessar propriedades de um objeto que não foi inicializado, no seu caso `patrimonio` da Classe `Marca`, em sua pergunta ela não possui nem os getters e setters

```
public class Marca
{
    public int MarcaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Patrimonio patrimonio {get; set;}
}
```

Mas o problema, de fato, está onde você está lendo o retorno do sql e tentando popular a lista de marcas, você cria uma instância de `Patrimonio`, não à utiliza e tenta atribuir valores para `Marca.patrimonio` que não foi incializada...

```
    while (leitura.Read())
    {
        Marca marca = new Marca();

        //AQUI ESTÁ O ERRO
        //Patrimonio patrimonio = new Patrimonio();

        marca.patrimonio = new Patrimonio();

        marca.patrimonio.Nome = (string)leitura["Nome"];
        marca.patrimonio.MarcaId =  (int)leitura["MarcaId"];
        marca.patrimonio.NumeroTombo = (int)leitura["NumeroTombo"];
        marca.patrimonio.Descricao = (string)leitura["Descricao"];

        marcas.Add(marca);

    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Leandro.Abç